# HashMap gets all values but returns only last entry

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am getting data from the hashmap.And i want to add it in the excel file using POI.But the problem is program adds only last item in excel.but while debugging its giving all values.
Here is my code

```
 for (int j = 0; j < proList.size(); j++) {
        HashMap hashMap = proList.get(j);
        Iterator<Object> iterator = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = (Map.Entry<String, String>) iterator.next();
            rows=sheet1.createRow(j+1);
            cc=rows.createCell(j);
            cc.setCellValue(entry.getValue());




        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by return? Are you sure it is saving all the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be creating the row in the outer loop.
And you probably need a separate index for the columns.

```
for (int j = 0; j < proList.size(); j++) {
    HashMap hashMap = proList.get(j);
    rows=sheet1.createRow(j+1);
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    int col = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();       
        cc=rows.createCell(col++);
        cc.setCellValue(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eran.. This is exactly what I was looking for 

Answer (score 0):

You are using j as the index which is never incremented inside your while loop. Hence its always creating only one row.

Note: The index 'j' which you are using is from the for loop declaration outside the while loop. Its limit will be only prolist.size()! I think you should use a separate index inside your while loop.